# Template literals with nested backticks(`) in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I write a template literal in ECMAScript 6 that will contain backticks(`) in and by itself, (i.e. nested backticks)?

For example:

```
var query = `
  UPDATE packet
  SET
  `association` = "3485435",
  `tagname` = "associated"
 `
```

---

The reason I need it:

It's quite obvious in my code example above.

I'm trying to build [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) queries as `Strings` and store them in a variable for passing them to MySQL. The MySQL query syntax requires back ticks for `UPDATE`-style queries.

- The only way I can have them look neat & tidy is by using template literals, otherwise the queries using regular single-line strings look awful because they end up being very long is some cases.
- I also want to avoid terminating lines using `\n` as it's cumbersome.

Comment: My instinct is to react with terror to the idea of plain template strings being used to construct SQL queries, but I guess you don't actually have any variables in your example, so there's no risk yet. Please be very careful (i.e.  don't) about adding variable interpolation here, unless you're using a template tag function specifically for constructing queries which is performing contextual autoescaping.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Hm, is this an SQL-injection-esque concern? If that's the case I'm using `connection.escape()` for each and every parameter that comes through my API which deals with this. I'm using [node-mysql driver](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) which contains this method.

Comment: Yeah, that's my concern. It's possible to write safe code using something like `connnection.escape()`, but that creates the possibility that you'll miss a parameter (or have the escaping removed by a mangled mere, or something). The general trend is away from anything that *ever* requires manual escaping, and into consistently using DB-provided APIs for explicitly providing values for query expressions. It looks like `node-mysql` sort-of uses the the common approach of letting you put `?` as a placeholder for values in the query, and pass the values as an array. I suggest that, despite issues.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I'll agree, however placeholders *can* be placed in a multi-line template string. So I'd say using template strings to construct SQL queries is fine as long I'm using placeholders and not `connection.escape()`, no?

Comment: Yup. That would be very reasonable, and probably nicely readable. The state of security in our industry is disgraceful and the stakes are quickly escalating, so I've become pretty pedantic and irritating whenever I hear something that *might* indicate a security problem, though it's sometimes a little unwarranted. :P

Comment: No no, I'll say thanks as you've saved me from the risk of omitting to `connection.escape()` a parameter.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

From [ES6 In Depth: Template strings by Jason Orendorff](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-template-strings-2/):

> If you need to write a backtick inside a template string, you must escape it with a backslash: ``` `\`` ``` is the same as `` "`" ``.

Your query should be:

```
var query = `UPDATE packet
  SET
  \`association\` = "3485435",
  \`tagname\` = "Simos"`
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use an apostrophe in a string made with apostrophes, you escape it with a backslash, like this:

```
'\''
```

Similarly, if you want to use a backtick in a template literal, you have to escape it with a backslash:

```
`\``
```

Answer (score 10):

See [11.8.6 Template Literal Lexical Components](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literal-lexical-components)

A template without substitutions is defined as

```
NoSubstitutionTemplate ::
    ` TemplateCharactersopt `
```

where a template character is

```
TemplateCharacter ::
    $ [lookahead ≠ { ]
    \ EscapeSequence
    LineContinuation
    LineTerminatorSequence
    SourceCharacter but not one of ` or \ or $ or LineTerminator
```

Therefore, `` ` `` can't be a template character unless you escape it by preceding it with `\`.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in other answers, you can escape the backtick `` ` `` with a backslash, like `` \` ``.

```sh
var tripleBacktickExample = `
\`\`\`python
# This JavaScript string contains some example Markdown that
# uses triple-backticks to delimit a Python code block.
\`\`\`
`
```

However, if you need very many backticks in a row `````` ````` `````` inside the template literal, it could be more readable to put them within a normal string that is inside a placeholder, like `````` ${'`````'} `````` or `````` ${"`````"} ``````.

````sh
var tripleBacktickExample = `
${'```'}python
# This JavaScript string contains some example Markdown that
# uses triple-backticks to delimit a Python code block.
${'```'}
`
````

Comment: @NikKyriakides Only the first half of my answer was mentioned in other answers. The second half of my answer demonstrates a new technique. I included examples of both techniques so one can directly compare them.

Answer (score 5):

To escape all special characters, not just the backticks:

```
let str = '`Hello`\\n${world}';
let escacped = str.replace(/\\|`|\$/g, '\\$&');
console.log(eval('`' + escaped + '`') === str); // test
```

I needed this for some code generation stuff. The `str` was the content of a JavaScript file and the goal was to put this content into a string literal variable into another generated JavaScript file.

Sadly it seems there is (2019) no native JavaScript function for this escaping. The characters that needs to be replaced are: `` ` ``, `$` and `\`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was injecting an html file as a string literal (with new lines) into a typescript file on the fly while transpiling with esbuild.

The gist being something similar to the following example:

```
// ...
let html = fs.readFileSync('./src/index.html', 'utf8');

// This escapes all instances of the three special characters
// that would break a backtick string literal definition: ` \ $
html = html.replace(/[`\\$]/g, '\\$&');

// ...

tsContents = tsContents.replace(
  /let html = [^;]+;/,
  () => `let html = \`${minified}\`;`,
);

return {
  contents,
  loader: 'ts',
};
```

The "magic" portion being:

```
.replace(/[`\\$]/g, '\\$&');
```

Comment: thanks bro, your regex can escape html string to string literal for react `<pre><code>` tags. Love this

Comment: any improvement for this? https://regex101.com/r/RTrzMO/5

Answer (score 2):

Use \`, it seems to work for me in the latest Chrome.

Comment: in node 4.8.3 and chrome \´ works          `\´´ doesnt work in either, the latter is mentioned often in other answers

Answer (score 2):

I found it easier to wrap the backticks in quotation marks to be easier. Here is an example you might use to start a code block in markdown:

````
const str = `${'```'}JavaScript`; // then the rest of whatever you need
````

So for your exact example

```
var query = `
UPDATE packet
SET
${'`'}association${'`'} = "3485435",
${'`'}tagname${'`'} = "associated"
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I consider ES6 template literals to be inadequate for SQL (and [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)) principally because you can't use backtick characters. I wish they would add triple-quoted strings to fix this properly.

In the meantime, since you're probably using a transpiler for ES6 anyway, you might consider using [triplet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/triplet) (disclaimer: I am the author).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a specific combination of characters to replace the backticks and use `replaceAll` afterwards to swap them.

Example:

```
var backtickReplace = `|replace_me_with_backtick_`;

var example = `This is a ${backtickReplace}back tick${backtickReplace}!`;

var result = example.replaceAll(backtickReplace, "`");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is not robust at all _and_ also cumbersome.

Comment: @SebastianSimon to be less abstract, what would be your definition of robust? What exactly is wrong about it? I'm open-minded to listen to better alternatives.

Comment: Well, such a replacement substring is really problematic to deal with, since you can’t encode the string `"|replace_me_with_backtick_"` itself with this method, which is an unnecessary restriction, given that the more robust approach — adding a backslash before the backtick — is trivial. Even if you don’t want to use backslashes, you could still make this much easier by using ``const backtick = "`";`` and `\`Some string using ${backtick}.\`` instead, which eliminates the need to use `replaceAll`. But both of these approaches are already covered by the other answers.

Answer (score -6):

ES6 has new features:

- Template literals
- Tagged template literals (tagged templates)

Which make working with strings easier. You wrap your text in `backticks`.

With this we can:

1. Interpolate variables

   ```
   let foo = "abc";

   console.log(`Welcome ${foo}`); // Welcome abc
   ```
2. Interpolate any kind of expression

   ```
   console.log(`2+3 = ${2+3}`) // 2+3 = 5
   ```
3. Declare strings with both ' and " quotation marks without having to
   escape anything.

   ```
   let foo = `foo is 'bar', "bar" is foo`

   console.log(foo); // "foo is 'bar', "bar" is foo"
   ```
4. Cleaner syntax for multi-line string

   ```
   let text = `foo is bar

   bar is foo`

   console.log(text);

   //"foo is bar

   //bar is foo"
   ```
5. Tagged templates, we can pass template literals to a function, here is how:

   ```
   let person = 'Mike';
   let age = 28;

   let output = myTag `that ${ person } is ${ age }`;

   function myTag(strings, personExp, ageExp) {

       // strings[0] gets value "that "
       // strings[1] gets value " is "
       // personExp  gets value " Mike "
       // ageStr     gets value "28"

       return strings[0] + personExp + strings[1] + ageExp;
   }

   console.log(output);

   // that Mike is 28
   ```
6. String.raw, we can get the raw form, here is the example:

   ```
   let text = String.raw `The "\n" newline won't result in a new line.'
   console.log(text);
   // The "\n" newline won't result in a new line.
   ```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The author is already using ES6 template strings, and they want to know how to write backticks inside them.