# How to add backticks into an URL string interpolation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a URL string that takes the BASE_PATH and fieldname string in order to match my API routes. Unfortunately the external database I am using includes spaces in the field names.

My api routes are along the lines of: localhost/api/data/fieldname

My fetch request looks like this:

```
const BASE_PATH = 'http://localhost:8082/api/data/'

  componentDidUpdate() {
    let URL = `${BASE_PATH}${this.props.fieldName}`
    fetch(URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.populateData(data))
    .catch(error => error);
  }
```

This works fine when the fieldname = education
but not so well when fieldname = marital status

The fetch request works when I wrap the fieldname in backticks eg. `marital status` but I can't fathom out how to amend the URL build to put backticks around ${this.props.fieldName} given that I am already using backticks in the string interpolation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the backticks:

```
 let URL = `${BASE_PATH}\`${this.props.fieldName}\``
```

Answer (score 2):

You can escape backticks with a backslash in template strings.

```
`${BASE_PATH}\`${this.props.fieldName}\``
```

See [Template literals with nested backticks(`) in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803959/template-literals-with-nested-backticks-in-es6)