# How to use ```code``` in my remark-gfm react-markdown website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, template-literals, remarkjs

My site is made using react-static and now I want to add remark-gfm.

To have a code snippet I use three ticks. To create a multiline section, I have to use a single tick. This breaks the triple tick code indicator.

My question is how to make multiline seconds so I can just copy paste my premade markdown files?

In the example I have a const markdown to show what works and how multiline breaks.

````
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'

const markdown = "```tmux ls```"
const multiline = `start tmux with 
                  ```tmux ls ```
                  `



export default () => (
            <ReactMarkdown children={markdown} remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]} />

)
````

Comment: Are you asking how to use backticks in template literals (which are enclosed with backticks)? The usual approach to this general problem is to escape with backslashes: `\\`\\`\\``

Comment: See [Template literals with nested backticks(`) in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803959/template-literals-with-nested-backticks-in-es6)